# Segmentation on Google Coral

Tags: google-coral

Could anyone provide an example workflow to train a new segmentation model to run on the Coral? Google has provided pretrained models to run on the Coral, but has not released any documentation on how to train a new segmentation model. Does anyone have a workflow that has worked for segmentation training and inference?